# Proving complete multipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose a graph $G=(V,E)$ has the property that if $uv \notin E, vw\notin E\implies uw\notin E$.  If this property holds then prove that it is a complete multipartite graph.

Now I am thinking to take the complement of a complete multipartite graph, which is a couple of complete isolated graphs. So, will the property also hold when I take the complement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph theory complete multiparite graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419569/graph-theory-complete-multiparite-graph)

Comment: Not really, I already saw that one and it seemed not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the relation $\sim$ on $V$ defined as

\begin{align}
\forall(a,b\in V):a\sim b\iff ab\notin E
\end{align}

Our condition implies that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Now, consider the quotient set $V/\sim$ and distinct classes $C,D\in V/\sim$.

First, we have $\forall(a,b\in C):ab\notin E$

Further, suppose $c\in C$ and $d\in D$.

If $cd\notin E$, then we have the contradiction $C=D$.

This proves that $G$ is a complete multipartite graph with the parts taken as classes of $V/\sim$.

Comment: Can you tell what V/∼ means?

Comment: @Mathnoob $V/\sim$ denotes the quotient set consisting of the equivalence classes: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class